# HIVE: How create a table with all columns in another table EXCEPT one of them?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I need to change a column into a partition ([convert normal column as partition column in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584143/convert-normal-column-as-partition-column-in-hive)), I want to create a new table to copy all columns except one. I currently have >50 columns in the original table. Is there any clean way of doing that?

Something like:

`CREATE student_copy LIKE student EXCEPT age and hair_color;`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to move the data as well? Or simply create an empty table?

Comment: Also want to copy data to create a new partition

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:
[CTAS using REGEX column spec.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification) :

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
CREATE TABLE student_copy AS SELECT `(age|hair_color)?+.+` FROM student;
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column;
```

BUT (as mentioned by [Kishore Kumar Suthar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3715328/kishore-kumar-suthar) :
this will not create a partitioned table, as that is not supported with [CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) (Create Table As Select).

Only way I see for you to get your partitioned table is by getting the complete create statement of the table (as mentioned by [Abraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4305965/abraham)):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE student;
```

Altering it to create a partition on the column you want. And after that you can use the select with regex when inserting into the new table.
If your partition column is already part of this select, then you need to make sure it is the [last column you insert](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts). If it is not you can exclude that column in the regex and including it as last. Also if you expect several partitions to be created based on your insert statement you need to enable 'dynamic partitioning':

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
INSERT INTO TABLE student_copy PARTITION(partcol1) SELECT `(age|hair_color|partcol1)?+.+`, partcol1 FROM student;
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column;
```

the 'hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none' is required to use the backticks '`' in the regex part of the query. I set this parameter to it's original value after my statement: 'hive.support.quoted.identifiers=column'

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE student_copy LIKE student;
```

It just copies the source table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE student_copy AS select name, age, class from student;
```

- Target cannot be partitioned table.
- Target cannot be external table.
- It copies the structure as well as the data

Answer (score 0):

I use below command to get the create statement of existing table.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE student;
```

Copy the result and modify that based on your requirement for new table and run the modified command to get the new table.